# Access to XMLHttpRequest at from origin has been blocked by CORS policy: with correct CORS policy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

[image]

I am getting this error, been stuck on this for a while. attaching my cors policy as well.
I am attaching the startup.cs file with my core policy.
Result of  dotnet --version
is 3.1.426

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            // services.AddMvc();
            // Add framework services.
            // Add framework services.
            // Add service and create Policy with options
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                    builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials() 
                    );
```

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

            StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("STRIPE_API_KEY");
            env.EnvironmentName = EnvironmentName.Production;

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");
            }

            app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
            {
                ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
            });

            app.UseSwaggerDocumentation();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseMvc();
```

Comment: When using AllowCredentials(), you cannot use AllowAnyOrigin() because the combination of allowing credentials and allowing all origins (*) is considered a security risk and is disallowed by browsers. Try change `builder.AllowAnyOrigin()` to `builder => builder.SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true)`